Many-to-many relationship query in django
I have a many-to-many relationship like this in django, how do I make it so that I can execute the query "get all books written by the author Mattia"
class Autore(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Libro(models.Model):
    titolo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    autori = models.ManyToManyField(Autore, related_name="libri")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titolo

In views.py i try to do this but i can't get the right object.
@api_view(["GET"])
def libri_autore(request, nome_autore):
    # Recupera l'autore dal database (si presuppone che il nome sia unico)
    autore = Autore.objects.get(nome=nome_autore)
    serializer = LibroAutoreSerializer(autore)
    print(autore)
    # Recupera tutti i libri associati a quell'autore
    libri = autore.libri.all()
    print(libri.values())
    return HttpResponse("Libri recuperati con successo")


autore.libri.all() should work fine. What exactly is the problem?

I can't output an Author object with an array of books

Do you mean to say you want to return the books along with the author object in the API response? Then ask that, "how do I make it so that I can execute the query get all books written by the author Mattia" is a completely different question the answer to which is already there in your code.

Mattia or Author is the exact same thing, in this exact case Mattia is an instance of author

it would be better to name your models in english for this site, that would help more people to understand what do you mean more explicit. So it seems that you have Author and related Books. If it's supposed that one book have one author you should use ForeignKey in your model:
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

then you can retrieve all author's books via:
Book.objects.filter(author = author.id) # assume your got author instance 
                                        # of Author

#or
Author.books.all() #if defined related name or:
Author.book_set.all() #default Django _set retrieval

If you want to get not just id, but Book instance:
in your serializers create serializer for Book(BookSerialyzer), then
in AuthorSerialyzer(yes, not BookAuthor, because you serialize models, not relations) define , that book should be not just an id, but instance of the model, do it by adding:
books = BookSerialyzer() #books is the name of the field, where you want 
                         # to get instances, not only IDs 

Actually i think there is problem with logic of your models, serializers. As I understood you want to get instance of author with field 'books', that is an Array of Book instances.

Thanks for the tips on writing in English.
Exactly, in my database I have to model the fact that an Author can have multiple books and a book can be written by multiple authors.

you should pay attention to using ChildModelSerialyzer inside ParentModelSerialyzer for geting array of ChildModel instances in the field, where was id number before:
code class AuhorSerialyzer(serializers.ModelSerializer): books = BookSerialyzer() #'books' name of the field where you got array of                                             #related books ids     class Meta:         model = Area         fields = "__all__" 

can't format it properly))

You can write this in your views.py;
autore = Autore.objects.prefetch_related('libri').filter(nome=nome_autore).first()
libri = Libro.objects.filter(autori__id=autore.id)

Now you have list of books from the autore in libri variable-queryset-
